# How to always begin SVG animation at start?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, code-snippets, svg-animate

I need many SVG to animate using the same `fill: url(#XXX)` however they all are running synchronously. I would like to have each SVG to start from the beginning of the animation when it is applied.

Here's my code demonstrating this.

```js
document.getElementById('first').style.fill = "url('#logo-gradient')"

setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById('second').style.fill = "url('#logo-gradient')"
}, 1000)
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<svg width="450px" height="195px">
    <defs>  
        <radialGradient id="logo-gradient" x1="50%" y1="50%" x2="50%" y2="50%" > 
            
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#E1AD21" stop-opacity="0">
                    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;"
                        begin="0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="0;1;1;0.8;0.4;0.2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;" begin="0" dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>

                <stop offset="12.5%" stop-color="#E1AD21" stop-opacity="0">
                    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;"
                        begin="0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="0;0.5;1;1;0.6;0.3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;" begin="0" dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>

                <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#E1AD21" stop-opacity="0">
                    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;"
                        begin="0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="0;0;0.5;1;1;0.6;0.3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;" begin="0" dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>

                <stop offset="37.5%" stop-color="#E1AD21" stop-opacity="0">
                    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;"
                        begin="0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="0;0;0;0.5;0.9;0.9;0.6;0.3;0;0;0;0;0;0;" begin="0" dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>

                <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#E1AD21" stop-opacity="0">
                    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;"
                        begin="0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="0;0;0;0;0.5;0.8;0.8;0.6;0.3;0;0;0;0;0;" begin="0" dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>

                <stop offset="62.5%" stop-color="#E1AD21" stop-opacity="0">
                    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;"
                        begin="0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="0;0;0;0;0;0.5;0.7;0.7;0.6;0.3;0;0;0;0;" begin="0" dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>

                <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#E1AD21" stop-opacity="0">
                    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;"
                        begin="0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="0;0;0;0;0;0;0.5;0.6;0.6;0.6;0.3;0;0;0;" begin="0" dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>

                <stop offset="87.5%" stop-color="#E1AD21" stop-opacity="0">
                    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#;#E1AD21;"
                        begin="0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0.5;0.5;0.5;0.6;0.3;0;0;" begin="0" dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>

                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#E1AD21" stop-opacity="0">
                    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;#E1AD21;"
                        begin="0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" values="0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0.5;0.5;0.5;0.5;0.3;0;" begin="0" dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>

        </radialGradient> 

    </defs>
  
    <g>
      <path id="first" d="M95 0L15 25L0 105L65 165L145 145L155 60z"></path>
      <path id="second" d="M295 0L215 25L200 105L265 165L345 145L355 60z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
<style>
  body {
    background-color: #eeeeee !important
  }
</style>
```

Could anyone propose a solution for this?

Many thanks

Comment: As far as I can see, there is one hard rule you cannot get around: if you write `url(#id)`, the referenced id must be a unique XML id in the DOM. There cannot be more than one element in the DOM with that id, and since the stops are children of the `radialGradient` element with that id (and not differentiated by the referencing element), there is only one animation with one timeframe for them. You would need a unique gradient for each referencing path with individual begin times for each of their animations.

Comment: That said, I have a very rough idea how to solve your problem differently, but it would be a fair amount of work to flesh out: 1. instead of a SVG, use a `<div>` with a `clip-path` for each of your shapes. 2. set a `background-image: radial-gradient()` for all of them and use a CSS animation for that gradient. That also has the advantage that the start time for CSS animations is measured from the application of the property to an element, instead of the document start time.